# Напишите программу, которая определяет максимальный элемент матрицы в заштрихованной области

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int N = 25;
    int matrix[N][N], k, a, b, m, p;
    cout << "Введите размер вашей матрицы: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "Как вы бы хотели задать матрицу?" << endl << "Нажмите 1, чтобы задать самостоятельно." << endl << 
        "Нажмите 2, чтобы задать случайные числа." << endl;
    cin >> p;
    if (p == 1) {
        k = a * b;
        cout << "Введите " << k << " чисел: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                cin >> matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else if (p == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Ваша матрица: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    m = matrix[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < b; j++) {
            if ((m < matrix[i][j] && j >= i && j >= a - i - 1) || (j <= i && j <= b - i - 1 && m < matrix[i][j]))
                m = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Наибольшее число: " << m<<endl;
}
```

Comment: матрица может быть не только квадратной

Comment: Так, и в чем вопрос?

Comment: программа выводит неверный ответ, в чём ошибка?

Comment: а вы сами понимаете смысль ваших условий в цикле?...

Comment: вроде бы да( делал подбором, чтобы ответ получился наиболее правдободобным:) )

Comment: в условии задачи должны быть  заданы соотношение строк и столбец.  Что касается того, что вы делаете, это совсем не то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Решение Вашей задачи крайте проста - при поиске максимума методом переопределения текущего максимального элемента прим -

```
auto i_border = size / 2; // пример (не является решением Вашей задачи)
auto j_border = size / 2; // пример (не является решением Вашей задачи)
auto tmp_max = a[0][0] // при условии что данный объект входит
for (auto i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
    for (auto j{0}; j < size; ++j) {
         if (a[i][j] > tmp_max && i < i_border && j <= j_border) {
             tmp_max = a[i][j];
         }
    }
}
```

Вам осталось только реализовать логику проверки входит или нет элемент в Вашу зону.

Вариант 2 сдампите Ваш массив в Vector с проверкой на условие что элемент в Вашей зоне. и дерните там max_element :

```
   std::vector<int> v;
    for (auto i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
        for (auto j{0}; j < size; ++j) {
            if (i < i_border && j <= j_border) {
                v.push_back(a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    auto it = max_element(std::begin(cloud), std::end(cloud));
```